# what is the difference between SVGForeignObjectElement API (supported by IE) and SVGForeignObject (not supported by IE)?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, foreignobject

I would like to use a `foreignObject` for a project.

I cannot test in IE.

On https://caniuse.com/#search=foreignobject I see that SVGForeignObjectElement API are supported by IE, but IE does not support SVGForeignObject.

But on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGForeignObjectElement I read it is just an element for reading properties of a SVGForeignObject.

So I am puzzled: which is the difference between the two ?

Can I use SVGForeignObject in IE ?

If not, is there any polyfill, or should I include in my application a fallback for IE  ?

Comment: I suspect that's simply a mistake in canIuse. IE does not support SVGForeignObjectElement API

Comment: Caniuse source the data from MDN. So I suggest you provide feedback about it to the MDN. I tried to search but did not get any alternative or polyfill to include it for IE 11 browser.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't have IE - can you tell me if at least is supported by IE 12+ ?

Comment: there is no such thing as IE 12+

Comment: holy molly I was misguided by caniuse.. :/